# Is it possible to create arbitrary stateful processes which perform exactly-once processing semantics with Apache Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I know that Kafka Streams can be used to create exactly once processing semantics on top of Apache Kafka, however Streams have two disadvantages:

- They are limited in the operations they can perform. They can't be used to build processes with arbitrary logic. While simple operations are relatively easy to implement, more complex logic is not. (Or in many cases more complex logic is simply impossible to implement.)
- To use them, one has to learn one of the two forms of "DSL".

I also know that for stateless processing, exactly once processing can be achieved using consumer and producers in combination with transactions. (With a bit of fiddling around to apply consumer group information to the transaction id.)

When it comes to stateless processing, there are two possible choices:

- Single processes (singletons) with state
- Processes (again, with internal state) which can be dynamically scaled horizontally as part of a consumer group

The first case is simpler.

Can exactly once semantics be achieved with a single process, when that processes has internal state? If so, what approach might be used to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

> They can't be used to build processes with arbitrary logic.

Can you explain why you say this? Given the Processor API, you should be able to implement any logic you want. I don't seen limitations that would prohibit you from doing so.

> To use them, one has to learn one of the two forms of "DSL".

There is just one DSL. The Processor API is a low level entry point (and not a "DSL") to assemble a data flow graph, and just a relatively simple abstraction over `KafkaConsumer` and `KafkaProducer`.

> Can exactly once semantics be achieved with a single process, when that processes has internal state? If so, what approach might be used to achieve this?

That is certainly possible, but `what approach might be used to achieve this` is a very open ended question and thus hard to answer. In the end, the recommendation is to use Kafka Streams that implements EOS for you. Note, that to get it right, it's more than just *"a bit of fiddling around to apply consumer group information to the transaction id"* -- I would estimate that 80% of EOS code inside Kafka Streams code base is error handling and edge cases... Don't underestimate the complexity.

Maybe the best start would really be to describe what logic you try to achieve to see if you can do it using Kafka Streams

Comment: In terms of the exact logic indended to be implemented with Kafka streams, again it is difficult to say exactly what this might be because it is indeed very open ended. A couple of examples I can think of: Something which calculates exponentially weighted moving averages. These have infinite history, but only a small amount of internal state to maintain. I don't expect such a transform would be impossible to describe with the DSL, but I don't think it is likely to be easy either. (Maybe you can prove me wrong on that?)

Comment: For another example, think the current number of contracts held in 30000+ equities stocks. The number of contracts in any stock could change at any time. I know this is just a simple aggregation option, but suddenly we are dealing with vast amounts of state which never goes away.

Comment: For something even more complex: Imagine you receive messages about the total amount of "product" you currently hold. When these messages come in, you need to forward on some information, distributing it according to a round-robbin algorithm depending on some other state which has arrived. This is perhaps a bit cryptic, so let me explain further: Two types of messages come in. One tells you how to split up some amount of something into relative portition. 50% should go to A, 20% should go to B, 30% should go to C. That sort of thing.

Comment: The other type of message is how much of this "stuff" do I need to round-robin distribute to A, B and C. This seems like a very hard thing to implement with Kafka Streams. It is trivial to implement in any general purpose programming language. Java, C++, Rust, Python, etc...

Comment: Really what I am getting at here is not the specific detail of any one particular problem, but just to conceptually show there are an infinite range of problems which would be very hard to implement in the DSL. I am **guessing** the DSL implements the typical operations that a functional language does. Map-reduce type stuff. (I'm absolutly not an expert here, I only just started looking into it.) The point being you could imagine having to maintain more and more state to implement some business logic and eventually trying to implement it in the DSL will become unworkable.

Comment: Yes, the DSL has pre-defined operator, but that's why there is customer `transform()` step, that allows you implement a call-back for every input record and also maintain state, so you can implement customer operator. If not much different to use the main consumer and do something for each input record (but it simpler because you don't have to worry about the low lever consumer details...). You just to `builder.stream(...).transform(...)` and only worry about the call-back per record instead of a `while(true) consumer.poll(...)` loop.